# Auto increment value in a dynamic cell formula, based on a length condition

Tags: xpath, lambda, while-loop, google-sheets-formula

Linked resource (accessible and editable): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_govdMo5Rc59sZRdzt_u2hJIzlKOL7s1mZYEBRfhYS8/edit#gid=0

**Context:**
I am attempting to automatically find the correct paragraph tag number in a webpage's html code (using xpath). The intention here is to show the course descriptions of each university subject that I have taken.

In column D, you can see that various cells xpath's p tag vary (between 11 and 14)
=CLEAN(TRIM(IMPORTXML(F2,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/p[***11***]/text()")))
=CLEAN(TRIM(IMPORTXML(F3,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/p[***12***]/text()")))

I have come across the LET and LAMBDA functions, but I'm having issues when attempting to intregate a 'while' loop type of approach.

**My current proposed approach (but more than willing to adjust)**:
Using column G as this automatic html, xpath, p tag, value incrementer, would it be possible to have each cell in this column to be self-referential around the character length of each p tag until it finds an entry from the website that could be the possible match, i.e., LEN(G2)<30?

**Curernt code:**
=TRIM(IMPORTXML(F2,"/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div[4]/div/p["&

LET(n,0,
LINEARSUM_,LAMBDA(self,n,IF(LEN(G23)>30,REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(n),LAMBDA(para,x,para+x)),REDUCE(0,SEQUENCE(n+1),LAMBDA(para,x,para+x)))),
LINEARSUM_(LINEARSUM_,n))

&"]/text()"))

Thanks so much for your thoughts and consideration.

Comment: This has been solved from another website. This was the code that was generated for this problem:

=CLEAN(TRIM(LET(i,IMPORTXML(F2,"//p"),INDEX(i,MATCH("Course Description:",INDEX(i,,1),0),2))))

Shout out to @HolyBonobos on Reddit.

Comment: Comments are temporary and maybe deleted. Consider adding a answer with appropriate credits.